# import QRCode constructor for Javascript through webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, qr-code

I want to use the QRCode generator from this repo: https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs

How do I import the QRCode through webpack? When I installed qrcodejs through npm the index.js contained this code `module.exports = 'qrcodejs';` When I use `require('qrcodejs');` in my code it returns the string 'qrcodejs', but I want to import the QRCode constructor through webpack. I want to be able to call the constructor in my code like so, after importing it with webpack.

```
let qrcode = new QRCode("output", { 
                                    text: "http://google.com", 
                                    width: 100, 
                                    height: 100, 
                                    colorDark: "#188710", 
                                    colorLight: "#ffffff" 
                                  });
```

What do I have to do to accomplish this? I am using ES6 Javascript without any frameworks or other libraries, besides webpack.

### UPDATE

index.js inside the qrcodejs folder

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /qrcode/, loader: 'exports-loader?QRCode' }
        ]
    }
}
```

myproject.js

```
  import { QRCode } from 'qrcodejs'

export class EditProduct {

     openProduct(){
        let test = require('qrcodejs'); // returns the module object with the rules array
         let test2 = QRCode // returns undefined
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Raz Ronen said, install [export-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader).

This will allow us to introduce non-modular js to Webpack.

After installing add the QRCode module as:

```
import QRCode from 'exports-loader?QRCode!qrcodejs/qrcode'
```

based on the answer [here](https://blog.csdn.net/github_37360787/article/details/81458570)

Comment: Thank you for giving me the missing puzzle piece I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [export-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader) to make `module.export = <anything you want>`

basiclly what you want is to have qrcode.min.js module.export return QRCode.

You can define a rule for it:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /qrcode/, loader: 'exports-loader?QRCode' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've installed export-loader, but if I try to export window.QRCode it returns an undefined. What am I supposed to export and where do I define this rule?

Comment: edited answer to export QRCode because I see that in their script they defined it as `var QRCode`. please tell me if it works or not

Comment: No it does not work. If I try to import QRCode I get an undefined and if I use the require function it just return the code I put in the module.export. I've updated my question to show you what I've done this time.

Comment: I probably have to add the export-loader to the require function like you you showed me in the export-loader documentation, but I don't know how to acces the file that way. If i try something like this: require("exports-loader?file!qrcodejs/index.js"); I get an error that the file is not defined

Comment: Hi @Jiren, most likely the regex of the loader wasn't correct because you didn't used minified version, so lets go with just `qrcode`, updated answer

Comment: if I use require("exports-loader?window.QRCode!qrcodejs/index.js") it seems to be going to the correct file however it returns an undefined

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean with the regex. I changed it, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: If I use require("exports-loader?window.QRCode!qrcodejs/index.js") I do not get an error but it simply returns undefined

Comment: If i user require("exports-loader?QRCode!qrcodejs/index.js");    I do get an error saying QRCode is not defined

Comment: I've changed the rule like you told me to